# Syntax error on token in if else

Tags: java, jquery, jsp

This error is raised:

> "Syntax error on token "int"
>   Invalid expression on the line `int = Integer.parseInt("status");`.

When the following code gets executed :

```
<%@page import="dao.admindao"%>

<jsp:useBean id="u" class="user.admin"></jsp:useBean>
<jsp:setProperty property="*" name="u"/>

<%
    int i=admindao.saveAssign(u);
    response.sendRedirect("assignedmanagement.jsp");
%>
<%

    String status = request.getParameter("status");
    int = Integer.parseInt("status");
    int qty = request.getParameter("qty");
    if(status.equals("APPROVED")){

    }

%>
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: It "keeps on saying that" because it's true. You're trying to assign a value to the keyword `int`. You probably meant `i = Integer.parseInt("status");` Or `int status = ...`. Not just `int =`.

Comment: How do you expect it to parse "Status" to an integer?

Comment: where is your variable name ??? define your variable

Answer (score 1):

There is no variable on that line.
Do,

```
int variablename = Integer.parseInt(status);
```

Answer (score 0):

you will have exception if you tried to parse `"status"` as String

you should parse the variable status

```
String status = request.getParameter("status");
Integer statusInteger = Integer.parseInt(status);
```